# If algebraic group $G$ acts faithfully on a $G$-qp variety $X$, then $G$ has a Faithful projective representation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, geometric-invariant-theory

In Michel Brion's survey on [Linearization of algebraic group actions](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Embrion/lin_rev.pdf)
is stated in Examples 3.2.2.(iv) following claim p 17
without proof:

We fix an algebraic group $G$ over field $k$ (of arbitrary characteristic).

> **Examples 3.2.2.**(iv) If G acts faithfully on a G-quasi-projective variety X, then G has a
> faithful projective representation, and hence is linear.

The part why $G$ obtains a **faithful** projective representation I not understand.
Where can I find a proof/ sketch of it?

Let's start naively with affine $G$-invariant cover of $X$ hopping that later later everything glues in the way we desire. Due to (i) is every affine $G$-variety $X$ is $G$-quasi-projective:
*Proposition 2.2.5* tells that such affine $X$ admits an equivariant immersion into some $G$-module $V$, and hence into the projectivization $\mathbb{P}(V \oplus k)$, where $G$ acts trivially on second summand $k$.

Glueing the stuff together we can extend the argument to $G$-quasi-projective variety $X$ and obtain a $G$-equivariant immersion $X \to \mathbb{P}(V \oplus k)$ and therefore by construction we obtain a $G$-action on projective space $\mathbb{P}(V \oplus k)$, therefore a projective representation of $G$.

But I not see why this induced projective representation of $G$ should be faithful, ie injective.

Comment: Since the faithful action of $G$ on $X$ is a restriction of the action on $\mathbb P(V \oplus k)$, the kernel of the action on $\mathbb P(V \oplus k)$ is contained in the kernel of the action on $X$, hence is trivial.